# xslt count max number of siblings

Tags: xslt

I have a large number of files with a structure like the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="a">aaa
      <div class="b">bbb</div>
      <div class="c">ccc1
        <div class="d">ddd11
          <div class="e">eee11</div>
          <div class="f">fff11
            <div class="g">ggg111</div>
            <div class="g">ggg112</div>
            <div class="g">ggg113</div>
            <div class="g">ggg114</div>
            <div class="g">ggg115</div>
            <div class="g">ggg116</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d">ddd12
          <div class="e">eee12</div>
          <div class="f">fff12
            <div class="g">ggg121</div>
            <div class="g">ggg122</div>
            <div class="g">ggg123</div>
            <div class="g">ggg124</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">ccc2
        <div class="d">ddd21
          <div class="e">eee21</div>
          <div class="f">fff21
            <div class="g">ggg211</div>
            <div class="g">ggg212</div>
            <div class="g">ggg213</div>
            <div class="g">ggg214</div>
            <div class="g">ggg215</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- The number of div class="c" is variable in each file (zero or more)
- The number of div class="d" is variable inside each 
  (zero or more)
- The number of div class="g" is variable inside each
   (zero or more)

For each file I want to find out the max count of  siblings.

For the example above, the max count of  siblings is 6.

I have tried the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='a']">
  <xsl:for-each select="div[@class='c']/div[@class='d']">
   <xsl:value-of select="count(div[@class='f']/div[@class='g'])" />
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This returns: 645, which is the count of the first, second and third group, that is 6, 4, and 5.

I would like it to return only the maximum count, that is 6.

Is there any way I could do this?

I thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@class='a']">
    <xsl:for-each select="div[@class='c']/div[@class='d']">
    <xsl:sort select="count(div[@class='f']/div[@class='g'])" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(div[@class='f']/div[@class='g'])" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is beautiful.  Thank you.